# Load huge amount of dummy data to DynamoDB global table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I want to create a DynamoDB global table and load huge data into it for testing purpose. The data is dummy data and has no special requirement. The global table data size is going to be 70GB.

I am going to use Jmeter to execute java sampler to load data on EC2 instance with DynamoDB VPC endpoint, the java sampler will use batchItemWrite to write data to table.

DynamoDB has limit on item size 400KB, even if I have used batchItemwrite and multiple jmeter threads to load the data. In order to load 70 GB data seems still require more than 24 hours.

Is there any better solution for better performance to load data to DynamoDB table? Any comment is appreciated.

Comment: Could you just use more EC2 instances?

Comment: Try to use Hive on  EMR, here is [a guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EMRforDynamoDB.Tutorial.CopyDataToDDB.html)